# Remove Unwanted File Path Values From Array

Tags: perl, cgi

I just cant seem to remove the "ExcludedFolders" values from the "Folders" array here is what I have, any help in appreciated.

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";


my @ExcludedFolders = qw(
/this/is/folder/path/one/exclude
/this/is/folder/path/three/exclude
/this/is/folder/path/five/exclude
);



my @Folders = qw(
/this/is/folder/path/one/exclude/some/file.dat
/this/is/folder/path/two/exclude/some/file.dat
/this/is/folder/path/three/exclud/some/file.dat
/this/is/folder/path/four/excludee/some/file.dat
/this/is/folder/path/five/exclude/some/file.dat
/this/is/folder/path/six/exclude/some/file.dat
);



my %remove;

@remove{@ExcludedFolders}=();
@Folders=grep{!exists$remove{$_}}@Folders;


foreach my $Path (@Folders) {
print "$Path \n";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because `'/this/is/folder/path/one/exclude/some/file.dat'` doesn't exist in the `%remove` hash; `'/this/is/folder/path/one/exclude/'` does.

I'd recommend using [`Tie::RegexpHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aRegexpHash) here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::RegexpHash;

my $remove = Tie::RegexpHash->new;

my @ExcludedFolders = qw(
    /this/is/folder/path/one/exclude
    /this/is/folder/path/three/exclude
    /this/is/folder/path/five/exclude
);

$remove->add( qr/^$_/ , 1 ) foreach @ExcludedFolders;

my @Folders = qw(
    /this/is/folder/path/one/exclude/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/two/exclude/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/three/exclud/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/four/excludee/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/five/exclude/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/six/exclude/some/file.dat
);

@Folders = grep { ! $remove->match_exists( $_ ) } @Folders;
```

Comment: Zaid, tried this and I get "Can't locate object method "matches" via package "Tie::RegexpHash" at Untitled line 29." any Ideas?

Comment: @Blnukem : My bad. It should've been `match`, not `matches`.

Comment: OK Zaid that fixed it but it returning the "unwanted" values of the array working backwards: @Folders = /this/is/folder/path/one/exclude/some/file.dat
/this/is/folder/path/three/exclude/some/file.dat
/this/is/folder/path/five/exclude/some/file.dat

Comment: @Blnukem : Negated the match with `!`.

Comment: Given that the paths start with `/`, shouldn't you anchor the patterns with `^`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no overlap in the two arrays. `@Folders` is misnamed since it is really files. I'm sure there's a better way, but I am busy:

```
## build a big regex to match exclude directories against
my $exclude_re = join '|', map { "\A\Q$_\E" } @ExcludedFolders;
my @filtered_files = grep { $_ !~ m{$exclude_re}i } @Folders;
```

Answer (score 1):

For each path in `@Folders`, you need to check if any of the excluded paths match an initial segment. [List::MoreUtils::none](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) comes handy here but it could easily be replaced with another `grep`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw( none );

my @ExcludedFolders = map qr{^$_}, qw'
    /this/is/folder/path/one/exclude
    /this/is/folder/path/three/exclude
    /this/is/folder/path/five/exclude
';

my @Folders = qw'
    /this/is/folder/path/one/exclude/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/two/exclude/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/three/exclud/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/four/excludee/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/five/exclude/some/file.dat
    /this/is/folder/path/six/exclude/some/file.dat
';

@Folders = grep {
    my $folder = $_;
    none {
        $folder =~ $_
    } @ExcludedFolders
} @Folders;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@Folders;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '/this/is/folder/path/two/exclude/some/file.dat',
          '/this/is/folder/path/three/exclud/some/file.dat',
          '/this/is/folder/path/four/excludee/some/file.dat',
          '/this/is/folder/path/six/exclude/some/file.dat'
        ];
```